# when i write code in hosting MySQL error come out

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE BBS (
  bbsID INT,
  bbsTittle VARCHAR(50),
  userID VARCHAR(20),
  bbsDate DATETIME,
  bbsContent VARCHAR(2048
  bbsAvailable INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (bbsID)
);
```

when i put this the error come out

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '`bbsAvailable INT,   PRIMARY KEY (bbsID) )`' at line 7

Comment: Have you read that error message? It tells you clearly that something around `bbsAvailable` is not okay, just like a missing closing parenthesis or so

Comment: Please look at your code.  If this is what it really looks like - then you have missing characters.

Answer (score 1):

you just missed closing (2048) parenthesis and comma after `bbsContent` column name

```
CREATE TABLE BBS (
  bbsID INT,
  bbsTittle VARCHAR(50),
  userID VARCHAR(20),
  bbsDate DATETIME,
  bbsContent VARCHAR(2048),
  bbsAvailable INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (bbsID)
);
```